# Add two sheets to an excel file with Response class

Tags: c#, excel

I have a piece of code for creating an excel file dynamically and then download it with c#, that works just fine. Here is the code:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=filename.xls");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

//ADD Headers
Response.Write("Name");
Response.Write("\t");
Response.Write("Age");
Response.Write("\t");
Response.Write("\n");

//ADD BODY
Response.Write("Shireen");
Response.Write("\t");
Response.Write("30");
Response.Write("\t");
Response.Write("\n");
```

Now the question is how to add a second sheet to this file. Is it even possible?

Comment: you are not creating an excel file, you are creating a tab separated values file which excel is able to open and display. That file format does not support having multiple sheets. There are libriries around the can help you creating and handling excel files. Have a look at [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/)

Comment: @Gian Paolo thank you very much. that was really helpful and informative.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an **Excel** file ?

Try that:

**Step 1**: Reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (available in Visual Studio) and using it:

`using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

**Step 2**: Example of using:

```
        private void CreateExcelFile(string sheet1Name, string sheet2Name)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog save = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
            save.Filter = "(All files)|*.*|(Excel)|*.xlsx|(Excel 97-2003)|*.xls";
            save.FilterIndex = 2;
            save.ShowDialog();
            if (save.FileName != "")
            {
                try
                {
                    // Create an Excel App
                    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
                    // Create a new Workbok                
                    Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                    // Creat a new WorkSheet
                    Excel.Worksheet ws = null;
                    app.Visible = false;

                    ws = wb.ActiveSheet;

                    // Name 1
                    ws.Name = sheet1Name;

                    // WorkSheet 2
                    Excel.Worksheet ws2 = wb.Sheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 1, Type.Missing);

                    // Name 2
                    ws2.Name = sheet2Name;

                    // Save
                    wb.SaveAs(save.FileName);
                    // Show the app
                    app.Visible = true;
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not a suitable solution when working in a web application as OP is, note he is trying to write the output file on the Response object. See this Microsoft [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) about the problems you can face, starting from the fact that you need Excel installed on the web server

Comment: @Shireen, Microsoft strongly discourage the use of Excel or every other Office program in a server side environment. I would actually suprised see it working, and anyway expect some problem later (for, e.g. an office Update that require a message box to show to the user). a library not requiring an interactive environmnet is the way to go. NPi and OpenXml are the first 2 I can suggest, the first one is probably easier to use